# scala get response from REST service

Tags: scala, playframework

I am working (and learning) Scala/Play at the minute, I am need to send a POST request to an external URL, and then dependent on the response status code, do 1 of 2 things,

If 200 push the response data into a view and display it.
If 400 show an error page.

I have written a connector that looks like this,

```
package connectors

import com.google.inject.Inject
import config.AppConfig
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.libs.ws.{WSClient, WSResponse}
import play.mvc.Http.Status
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import play.api.libs.json._
class RegisterConnector @Inject() (appConfig: AppConfig, ws: WSClient) {

  val customerBaseUrl: String = appConfig.customerBaseUrl

  def verifyCustomer(code: String): Future[Boolean] = {
    ws.url(s"$customerBaseUrl/customer/$code").post(code).map(processResponseStatus)
  }

  private def processResponseStatus(resp: WSResponse): Boolean = resp.status match {
    case code if (Status.OK until Status.MULTIPLE_CHOICES).contains(code) => true
    case _ => throw new RegisterException(s"Server error: ${resp.status} . ${resp.body}");
  }

}

class RegisterException(message: String) extends RuntimeException(message: String)
```

I then use my connector in my controller, but I cannot work out a) how to parse the response if the status code is 200, and b how to detect an error, can anyone help me please, here is my current controller,

```
    package controllers

import com.google.inject.{Inject, Singleton}
import config.AppConfig
import play.api.i18n.{I18nSupport, MessagesApi}
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import connectors.RegisterConnector
import play.api.Logger
import views.html.register.verified

@Singleton
class VerifiedController @Inject()(registerConnector: RegisterConnector,
                                    val messagesApi: MessagesApi)
                                   (implicit appConfig: AppConfig) extends Controller with I18nSupport {

  def verify(code: String): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>

    registerConnector.verifyCustomer(code).map {
      case true =>

      case _ =>

    }.recover {
      case ex =>

    }

  }

  def show(): Action[AnyContent] = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    Ok(verified())
  }

  def error(): Action[AnyContent] = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    Ok(verified())
  }

}
```

Some help and guidance would be fantastic!

Comment: Is it JSON the response format?

Comment: It does indeed return JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming JSON is the response format, I usually start wrapping the response structure in a case class.
Assuming the following JSON response:

```
{
  "city": "Vienna",
  "forecast": 10
}
```

Now the case case would look like this:

```scala
case class WeatherUpdate(city: String, forecast: Int)
```

the strategy of using a singleton to make your API calls is a pretty good one. Lets call this guy `WeatherService`. instead of returning a `Future[Boolean]` you can use Scala standard library `Try`.

```
class WeatherService @Inject() (ws: WSClient) {

  private val logger = Logger(getClass)

  def getWeather(): Future[Try[WeatherUpdate]] = {
    ws.get("https://myweather.com/api/update") // this is all fake
      .map {
        case response if response.status == 200 =>
          val city = (response.json \ "city").as[String]
          val forecast = (response.json \ "forecast").as[Int]
          Success(WeatherUpdate(city, forecast))
        case response =>
          Failure(new WeatherException("Could not get weather response"))
      }.recover { // always recover from a future. It could throw an exception and you would never know
        case ex: Exception =>
          logger.error("could not get weather info", ex)
          Failure(ex)
      }
  }

}

class WeatherException(message: String) extends RuntimeException(message: String)
```

On your controller, now you can render your template using the weather update:

```scala
def verify(code: String): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { 
  implicit request =>
    weatherService.getWeather().map {
      case Success(weatherUpdate) => Ok(weather_template(weatherUpdate))
      case Failure(ex) => BadRequest(weather_error())
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks in the WeatherService what does Success and Failure pertain too?

Comment: To quote this article: https://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/26/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-6-error-handling-with-try.html

`Try[A]` represents a successful computation, it is an instance of `Success[A]`, simply wrapping a value of type `A`. If, on the other hand, it represents a computation in which an error has occurred, it is an instance of `Failure[A]`, wrapping a `Throwable`, i.e. an exception or other kind of error.